# Existing Realm Database notworking in swift 3.1 xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I created the application use existing database realm 2.3.0 and swift 3.1 xcode 8.3.
But when I try to access the realm database. there is an error.

> Could not access database:  Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/dodipurnomo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/858C796B-CBA8-424B-9A97-0893304B758B/data/Containers/Data/Application/A2D910EE-AAC5-4836-9FE7-97F744E802E5/Documents/Conversio.realm': Unsupported Realm file format version." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/dodipurnomo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/858C796B-CBA8-424B-9A97-0893304B758B/data/Containers/Data/Application/A2D910EE-AAC5-4836-9FE7-97F744E802E5/Documents/Conversio.realm,

Above is an error message when I try to execute the database.
As for the class to hendleing the database realm is as follows:

```
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class DBManager{
//MARK: - Singleton shared intance

static let sharedIntance = DBManager()
//MARK: - overide init function in realm

static var realm: Realm {
    get {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            return realm
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not access database: ", error)
        }
        return self.realm
    }
}

public static func write(realm: Realm, writeClosure: () -> ()) {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            writeClosure()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not write to database: ", error)
    }
}

public static func query(realm: Realm,queryClosure: () -> ()){

}


func save(entityList: [Object], shouldUpdate update: Bool = false) {
    DBManager.realm.beginWrite()
    for entity in entityList {
        if let key = type(of: entity).primaryKey(), let value = entity[key] , update {
            if let existingObject = DBManager.realm.object(ofType: type(of: entity), forPrimaryKey: value as AnyObject) {
                let relationships = existingObject.objectSchema.properties.filter {
                    $0.type == .array
                }
                for relationship in relationships {
                    if let newObjectRelationship = entity[relationship.name] as? ListBase , newObjectRelationship.count == 0 {
                        entity[relationship.name] = existingObject[relationship.name]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        DBManager.realm.add(entity, update: update)
    }

    do {
        try DBManager.realm.commitWrite()
    } catch let writeError {
        debugPrint("Unable to commit write: \(writeError)")
    }

    DBManager.realm.refresh()
 }
}
```

> And I set the Realm in appdelegate as follows:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let desPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let fullDesPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: desPath).appendingPathComponent("Conversio.realm")


    var config = Realm.Configuration()
    config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
    config.fileURL = fullDesPath
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    chekDB()
    return true
}


//chek database
func chekDB() {
    let bundleDB = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Conversio", ofType: "realm")
    let desPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let fullDesPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: desPath).appendingPathComponent("Conversio.realm")
    let fullDestPathString = String(describing: fullDesPath)
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullDesPath.path){
        print("Database file is exis !")
        print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bundleDB!))
    }else{
        do{
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundleDB!, toPath: fullDesPath.path)
        }catch{
            print("error encured while copying file to directori \(fullDestPathString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The important part of the error message is "Unsupported Realm file format version"

Answer (score 2):

The error message you're getting means that realm file was created with newer version of Realm, so update Realm to the latest version.

Also keep in mind if you open realm with Realm Browser that uses a newer version of realm it asks you to convert the file format. If you do that you can open this realm with older version of realm-cocoa.